# Invoices: Need to get hours cell "value" from mulitple workbooks. Using Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I got dragged into this by my wife and I'm struggling.

Setup: There are 700+ workbooks someone used to create Invoices for their work.  They are all located in the same folder.  They used one new book per job and "Sheet 1" only.  In cell "D33" they recorded how many hours it took (0,1, 2.5, .5, etc).  In "D35" they recorded their "travel time" (2.5, 3, etc) and "D37" they recorded the mileage it took to get there.  The cell directly above them say the title. (i.e D32 says "hours", while D33 has the value.)  These cells are consistent in purpose, but not always filled in.  The upper part of the column is also used for text values "name, number, part s/n" so they may also have numeric values.

My question:  How can I pull the "hour", "mileage" and "travel time" values of those specific cells for a summary value?

I've tried to filter a query, but seem to miss values. The goal is to answer "how many invoices, this many hours worked, this many miles driven".  I'm using excel 2016 power query to count the books in the folder, then needed these cells.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer by creating a function query.  Created three functions then the queries with functions.  Used the "Combine Multiple Excel Workbooks in Power Query" by Ken Puls (dated Feb 25, 2015) to get a work around. 1500 invoices completed in five seconds.  (https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/02/25/combine-multiple-excel-workbooks-in-power-query/)